# How to convert string with a specific date format like 'mm/dd/yy' to date object in hibernate query

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, hql

One of the columns my_column in my table is of type varchar where i store value of date in string. The format is `'MM/DD/YY'`. I want to use cast function of hibernate to convert this column value to date. But it appears that the cast function accepts string of `'yy-mm-dd'` format to convert. Is it possible to use cast for string with specific date format for conversion. Something like this: `cast(am.my_column as date format 'mm/dd/yy')`

cast function in hibernate is used this way: cast(am.my_column as date).
My use case is basically converting the column value from string to date and making a date comparison.  `cast(am.my_column as date format 'mm/dd/yy') > '12/30/2017'`

Comment: You can always use substring and concatenation to build a string which `cast` can consume.

Comment: Please share your whole code, it will be much helpful.

Comment: There is no associated relevant code as such. By HQL Query is something like this: select * from am where cast(am.my_column as date) > 'The date string passed from client side'

Comment: How are you passing the date from clientside?

Comment: @chsdk
In my_column i am saving the date as string format 'MM/DD/YY' and the date for comparison '12/30/2017' is also passed from the js as string.

Comment: Please update your question will the relevant codes, so we can get the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting a column value inside the query, you may consider to give '12/30/2017' as parameter (with type of Java Date). So that you can directly write `am.my_column > :parameterDate`